# What would Camus say to the objection that some people live short and very happy lives?

Tags: existentialism, camus, absurdism

I have read Camus, a fairly long time ago now; feels like I didn't get the intensity then, but I'm going through the wikipedia pages, and google to get an answer. If this is the wrong site I'll go to reddit.

What would Camus say to the objection that some people live short and very happy lives?

I *think* that it follows that we must *at least* be willing to risk our life.

Comment: See [La mort heureuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Happy_Death) : the basic Camus' question is "a monotone and empty life is worth to be lived ?"